# jQuery load div into another without .html() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a div (let's call it potatoes) that I want to appear inside another div (food). The typical way to do this would be:

```
$("#food").html ( $("#potatoes").html());
```

However this doesn't accomplish what I want. Instead of using the actual "potatoes" div, jQuery seems to be *copying* that content into the food div, where the original content still exist in the browser.

I want the ACTUAL div (potatoes) to disappear from its place and to appear in the container div (food) without having to do perform .hide() ... or similar methods.

Reason why? I have selectors that enable and disable buttons in the potatoes div, and they seem to trigger the original potatoes div content, but NOT the duplicate that has been loaded into the food div.

Does that make sense? Can anyone give insight as to why this is and what I should do?

**Side note:**

```
$(document).on('click','#button-loaded-with-page', {} ,function(e){
    this.disabled = true;
    $('#button-inside-potatoes-div').hide();
});
```

The above example is what I would like to achieve, but does NOT hide the button when the potatoes content has been loaded into food by the `.html()` method. Instead it hides the original button on the page, and not the duplicated one.

What I am trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/o9kshscj/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just pass the object to [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$("#a").html($("#b"));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/coLohena/)

Comment: The jQuery docs don't mention anything about being able to pass a jQuery object into `html()`. How does this work out of interest?

Comment: @RGraham in the `html` code you can find `if ( elem ) {
    this.empty().append( value );
   }`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Interesting! They really should document that. Can't believe you've got the source memorized :)

Comment: @RGraham I had the same question before when I saw it somewhere.. so went to the source and searched and found this.. now since I remembered it I went to the source and copied it

Answer (score 3):

You could use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to change the parent. This will *move* the `#potatoes` object out of it's current DOM position, into the `#food` div as a child

```
$("#food").append($("#potatoes"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the div after replacing like this:

```
$("#a").html($("#b").html());
$("#b").remove();
$("#button-to-enable").prop("disabled", false);
```